# MySQL: turn decimal into percent within view

Tags: mysql, view

I've inherited a database and am using views in MySQL to return specific information from a database. I'm having a little trouble one portion- turning the returned numeric value that is a decimal into a percentage.

I don't want to do this in the php- I am specifically trying to format everything in the view first. I realize this is not necessarily the way everyone does this, but for my specific situation it is the best overall solution.

The example value in the database: 0.46

What I'd like to have returned: 46%

Relevant portions of current query:

```
    SELECT CONCAT(a.fa_rate, '%') as rate_percent
    FROM accounts a;
```

This returns 0.46%. Is it possible to return the result I want to have without converting the number into a string? The current data type is a float.

Comment: is your problem related with your query returning '0.46%' instead of '46%'? multiply the number by 100 and concatenate it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

```
   SELECT CONCAT(a.fa_rate * 100 , '%') as rate_percent
   FROM accounts a;
```

Comment: this works, although that returned really long percentages. I added a LEFT concat statement inside and it returns just the two digit percentage. Thank you!! (will accept as answer once allowed).