# MySql: turn decimal to percent upon viewing the table

Tags: mysql

I saw a post here in stack overflow with question and answer very similar to my problem.
its this post:
[MySQL: turn decimal into percent within view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931049/mysql-turn-decimal-into-percent-within-view)

and as said in the post above, use:

```
CONCAT(columnname * 100, '%')
```

and thats what i actually did..
i have a table with a column for percentages for specific ranges of salary.
its a salary deduction schedule.
i stored the percent values as a decimal datatype in column "ee".

```
ee | decimal(4,4) | not null
```

and my problem is its giving me this result and its not what i wanted..
for example, an entry in the column is `0.0200`, and i want to show it upon viewing as "`2%`", but this is what i get.

```
select s_b,rangeA,rangeB,concat(ee * 100,'%') as 'ee_percent' from htbl;

+___________________________________+
|s_b|  rangeA|   rangeB|ee_percent  |
+---+--------+---------+------------+
|  1|    0.00|  1500.00|   1.0000%  |
|  2| 1500.00|999999.99|   2.0000%  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I know that this is a duplicate and an elementary question, but i don't know why its not working,
if you see a mistake somewhere in my syntax, or in the data type please tell me.
any suggestions and corrections are highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format):

```
SELECT s_b, rangeA, rangeB, CONCAT(FORMAT(ee * 100, 0), '%') AS 'ee_percent'
FROM htbl;
```

The result of the calculation is always `DECIMAL(4,4)`. So MySQL show the result with four decimal places. You can use the `FORMAT` function to format the result or other functions which remove the decimal places.

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ncjBpJRwdQVbT7PUBoXgeU/0

Comment: i tested all suggested answers, and i think i like this one, because it allows me to adjust the decimal places the way i like it. thank you so much, i've learned something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Floor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) function,

```
select s_b,rangeA,rangeB,concat(FLOOR(ee * 100),'%') as 'ee_percent' from htbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **round**, i.e:

```
select s_b,rangeA,rangeB,concat(round(ee * 100),'%') as 'ee_percent' from htbl;
```